# Form Value not able to pass to service and update the city value

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and trying to build a simple weather application. Whenever I try to pass the value of city in the form on ngSubmit to the api service, it's not at all working. I have tried to pass the value using Emitter Event, but it seems that the city value is not getting updated in the service. Is there a way, how we can send this value to the api service and update the city name.

weather-card.component.html

```
<div class="input-container">
  <app-weather-form></app-weather-form>
</div>
<div *ngFor="let item of weathers[0]; first as isFirst">
  <div *ngIf="!isFirst">
    <mat-card class="mat-card">
      <p><strong>Name :</strong>{{ item.name }}</p>
      <p><strong>State :</strong> {{ item.region }}</p>
      <p><strong>Country :</strong>{{ item.country }}</p>
      <p><strong>Latitude:</strong> {{ item.lat }}</p>
      <p><strong>Longitude:</strong> {{ item.lon }}</p>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

weather-card.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from '../../services/weather.service';
import { WeatherData } from '../../models/weather';
import { WeatherFormComponent } from '../weather-form/weather-form.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather-card',
  templateUrl: './weather-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather-card.component.scss'],
})
export class WeatherCardComponent implements OnInit {
  weathers: any = [];

  constructor(public weatherService: WeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.weathers = Object.entries(data);
      console.log(this.weathers);
    });
  }
}
```

weather-form.component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  City:<br />
  <input type="text" name="city" [(ngModel)]="name" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

weather-form.component.ts

```
import { WeatherService } from 'src/app/services/weather.service';
import { WeatherData } from 'src/app/models/weather';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather-form',
  templateUrl: './weather-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather-form.component.scss'],
})
export class WeatherFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onSelection: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  weather!: WeatherData;
  name!: '';
  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  submit() {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherData().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.onSelection.emit(this.weather);
    });
  }
}
```

weather.ts

```
export interface WeatherData {
  name: string;
  region: string;
  country: string;
  humidity: string;
  localtime: string;
  lat: string;
  lon: string;
}
```

weather.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';

let serviceUrl: String = 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json';
let apiKey: String = 'someAPIKey'; // insert your API key here
let name: String = 'mumbai';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class WeatherService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getWeatherData() {
    return this.http.get(
      serviceUrl + '?key=' + apiKey + '&q=' + name + '&aqi=no'
    );
  }
}
```

In the weather.service.ts file, I wanted to change the value of name by passing the value from form and pass it to the URL. Currently, I have hard coded the value.

Answer (score 0):

You strong typed the interface to the form - and on your interface you have no city value.

```
export interface WeatherData {
      name?: string;
      region?: string;
      country?: string;
      humidity?: string;
      localtime?: string;
      lat?: string;
      lon?: string;

      /// add
      city?: string;
}
```

When one uses strong typing unknown data is discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Your `city` input is bound to `name` property on `WeatherFormComponent` but you're not using that property at all. If you want to pass that value to a function of `WeatherService` just pass it as a parameter:

WeatherFormComponent:

```
submit() {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherData(this.name).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.onSelection.emit(this.weather); // not sure what's the purpose of this event
    });
  }
```

WeatherService:

```
getWeatherData(name?: string) {
   // You need to handle the case where name is undefined
    return this.http.get(
      serviceUrl + '?key=' + apiKey + '&q=' + name + '&aqi=no'
    );
  }
```